# Calculate state transition matrix with one left and right eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, control-theory

How is it possible to calculate the state transition matrix of the following LTI-System:

$$
\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\pmatrix {1 \\ -1}u$$
$$y=\pmatrix {2 & -2}\mathbf{x}$$
$$s_1=2,s_2=-1$$
$$\mathbf{p}_{r1}=\pmatrix {1 \\ 1},\mathbf{p}_{l1}=\pmatrix {0 \\ 1}
$$
$s_1$ and $s_2$ are the known eigenvalues of $\mathbf {A} $, $\mathbf{p}_{r1}$ is the right eigenvector and $\mathbf{p}_{l1}$ the left eigenvector, both belonging to the $s_1$.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbf A$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 3):

You have to reconstruct the (right) eigenbasis of $A$ first. Since two eigenvectors are given, there is enough information to find the second right eigenvector. 
Let $v$ denote this eigenvector, then $Ap_{r2}=-p_{r2}$.

Multiplying this from the left by $p_{l1}^T$, we get
$$
-p_{l1}^Tp_{r2} = p_{l1}^TAp_{r2} = 2p_{l1}^Tp_{r2},
$$
which proves $p_{l1}^Tp_{r2}=0$. Hence $p_{r2}=\pmatrix{1\\0}$ is such a vector. Now you can proceed with standard techniques.